# convert List<object> to map

Tags: java

I have an `Employee` class that contain four fields: id, name, department, and email. I have created five objects, set the values and added all of them to a list.

Now, I want to convert that list to map but I am not able to. For your reference, here is the code that I tried

```
Employee emp1 = new Employee("1", "Mayank", "HR", "mayank@gmail.com");
Employee emp2 = new Employee("2", "Mahesh", "Trainer", "Mahesh@gmail.com");
Employee emp3 = new Employee("3", "Vipul", "SEO", "Vipul@gmail.com");
Employee emp4 = new Employee("4", "Ajay", "Devlopwr", "Ajay@gmail.com");
Employee emp5 = new Employee("5", "Rakesh", "Marketing", "Rakesh@gmail.com");

//add class object to list
List < Employee > listWmp = new ArrayList < > ();
listWmp.add(0, emp1);
listWmp.add(1, emp2);
listWmp.add(2, emp3);
listWmp.add(3, emp4);
listWmp.add(4, emp5);
System.out.println("list elements are : " + listWmp);
//convert the list into map
Map < String, Employee > listMap = new HashMap < > ();
for (Employee employee: listWmp) {
  listMap.put(employee.getEmpId(), employee.getEmpBame());
}
```

How do I convert the list to a map?

Comment: Why create a list at all? Just create the hashmap, then call `put` 5 times rather than `add`

Answer (score 6):

The best way is to use a Stream and then collect the employee:

```
Map<String, Employee> listMap = listWmp.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Employee::getEmpId, employee -> employee));
```

Or if you don't want to use Java Stream API you have to change your code to:

```
listMap.put(employee.getEmpId(), employee);
```

Comment: Second param can be `Function::identity`

Comment: Yes but if this is more readable for beginners...

Answer (score 3):

> A `Map` is an object that maps keys to values.

Your `Map` is defined as `Map<String, Employee>`. So it maps a `String` to an `Employee`.

When you try to execute :

```java
listMap.put(employee.getEmpId(), employee.getEmpBame());
```

It fails because the second parameter is supposed to be an instance of `Employee` but `employee.getEmpBame()` returns a `String`.

You should replace it with :

```java
listMap.put(employee.getEmpId(), employee);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should/may do like this:

```
Employee emp1 = new Employee("1","Mayank","HR","mayank@gmail.com");
    Employee emp2 = new Employee("2","Mahesh","Trainer","Mahesh@gmail.com");
    Employee emp3 = new Employee("3","Vipul","SEO","Vipul@gmail.com");
    Employee emp4 = new Employee("4","Ajay","Devlopwr","Ajay@gmail.com");
    Employee emp5 = new Employee("5","Rakesh","Marketing","Rakesh@gmail.com");
        
         List<Employee> listWmp = new ArrayList<>();
         listWmp.add(emp1);
         listWmp.add(emp2);
         listWmp.add(emp3);
         listWmp.add(emp4);
         listWmp.add(emp5);
        
         Map<String, Employee> listMap = new HashMap<>();
         for (Employee employee : listWmp) {
             listMap.put(employee.getEmpId(), employee);
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

## Hard-code a `Map`

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74853815/convert-listobject-to-map/74856621#comment132101424_74853815), in your particular example you could simply [hard-code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_coding) a `Map` rather than hard-code a `List`.

```java
Employee emp1 = new Employee("1", "Mayank", "HR", "mayank@gmail.com");
Employee emp2 = new Employee("2", "Mahesh", "Trainer", "Mahesh@gmail.com");
Employee emp3 = new Employee("3", "Vipul", "SEO", "Vipul@gmail.com");
Employee emp4 = new Employee("4", "Ajay", "Devlopwr", "Ajay@gmail.com");
Employee emp5 = new Employee("5", "Rakesh", "Marketing", "Rakesh@gmail.com");

Map < String , Employee > mapEmpIdToEmp = new HashMap < > ();
mapEmpIdToEmp.put( emp1.id() , emp1 );
mapEmpIdToEmp.put( emp2.id() , emp2 );
mapEmpIdToEmp.put( emp3.id() , emp3 );
mapEmpIdToEmp.put( emp4.id() , emp4 );
mapEmpIdToEmp.put( emp5.id() , emp5 );
```

### `Map.of`

The [`Map.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#of(K,V,K,V,K,V,K,V,K,V)) method in modern Java makes literal map instantiation quite easy and readable. The resulting `Map` is [unmodifiable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#unmodifiable).

```java
Map < String , Employee > mapEmpIdToEmp = 
    Map.of(
        emp1.id() , emp1 ,  // key , value 
        emp2.id() , emp2 ,
        emp3.id() , emp3 ,
        emp4.id() , emp4 ,
        emp5.id() , emp5
    );
```

## `List.of`

Indeed, you could use [`List.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#of(E,E,E,E,E)) for hard-coding those 5 new `Employee` objects into an [unmodifiable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#unmodifiable) `List`.

```java
List< Employee > employees = 
    List.of(
        new Employee("1", "Mayank", "HR", "mayank@gmail.com") ,
        new Employee("2", "Mahesh", "Trainer", "Mahesh@gmail.com") ,
        new Employee("3", "Vipul", "SEO", "Vipul@gmail.com") ,
        new Employee("4", "Ajay", "Devlopwr", "Ajay@gmail.com") ,
        new Employee("5", "Rakesh", "Marketing", "Rakesh@gmail.com")
    );
```

From that list, build your map in a soft-coded manner.

```java
Map < String , Employee > mapEmpIdToEmp = new HashMap < > ();
for( Employee employee : employees ) 
{
    mapEmpIdToEmp.put( employee.id() , employee ) ;
}
```

If desired, call [`Map.copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#copyOf(java.util.Map)) to make an [unmodifiable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#unmodifiable) map from `mapEmpIdToEmp`.